# Set maximum number for input in TextBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, validation

I have a text box in a loan calculator program and the maximum amount of months for user input needs to be set at 84, how do I set the text box to reject any number over 84?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [NumericUpDown control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/729xt55s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of a Textbox if you only want the user to input a numeric value. You can then set the [Maximum property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.maximum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to 84

Answer (score 0):

In the textbox's TextChanged even, add something like this -

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
         If Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text) > 84 Then TextBox1.Text = "84"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
Private Sub Textbox1_OnValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox1.OnValueChanged
    If Val(Textbox1.Text) > 84 Then Textbox1.Text = "84"
End Sub
```